# How to call the method available in Android and iOS project from Xamarin Forms project?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, dependencies

I do have a button in my Xamarin Forms Page. Whenever the button is clicked, I need to call the method in Android Project (in MainActivity.cs) if the device is Android and call the method in iOS Project (in AppDelegate.cs) if the device is iPhone.

Can someone help me how can I do this?

A method in Xamarin Forms

```
private async void BtnStart_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if Android call StartBeepWork in MainActivity.cs else call StartBeepWork in AppDelegate.cs
}
```

The method in MainActivity.cs and AppDelegate.cs

```
public void StartBeepWork()
{
    //process
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) is for. So you define the interface in the shared project, and implement it for each supported platform in the platform-specific project.

```
public interface IBeepWork
{
    void Start();
}
```

In your Android project:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BeepWorkAndroid))]
public class BeepWorkAndroid : IBeepWork
{
    public void Start()
    {
        // Android-specific implementation
    }
}
```

You can do the same for the iOS project:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BeepWorkiOS))]
public class BeepWorkiOS : IBeepWork
{
    public void Start()
    {
        // iOS-specific implementation
    }
}
```

Then in your code-behind you can resolve the platform-specific instance by calling `DependencyService.Get`:

```
private async void BtnStart_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DependencyService.Get<IBeepWork>().Start();
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is what I am looking for. Thanks for the example.

Comment: Please help me. I need to do exactly the opposite. I need to call the save method, which is in a public project from an android project, how can I do this?